# Route53 alias for S3 and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, but my problem is this. I'm hosting my web app on aws as an Elastic Beanstalk application. The EC2 instance created has a load balancer associated with it.

I also have a domain registered on aws, and on Route 53, I have an A type configured for the domain and the alias target is the load balancer. That's all working fine.

I also wish to host a static html page for my domain. But to do that according to this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-add-arecord-to-hostedzone, I also need to create another A type alias in Route 53 for the S3 bucket.

The problem is I cant seem to be able to have both. Is there a way to configure my load balancer and/or Route 53 settings to be able to host and serve my static website and my elastic beanstalk instance?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unless you use a reverse proxy like Nginx (in front of ELB) to serve your static page (hosted on S3) on different port or port 443 but on different uri like `https://<yourdomain.com>/static` and serve your Elastic Beanstalk web app on port 443 on uri / like `https://<yourdomain.com>`.

`<yourdomain.com>` -> DNS A record -> Nginx server -> route to ELB or your static page (hosted on S3) depending on which port/uri was requested.

OR

Host your static html page on an EC2 instance and setup a rule on ELB to route requests with `/static` in URL path to that EC2 instance. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/

Comment: I actually got it working by creating a new certificate and new hosted zone for the subdomain `api.mydomain.com`. Then created an alias in the new zone and associated it with the load balancer.

In my original `mydomain.com` zone, I created a CNAME entry for the new certificate and an alias for `api.mydomain.com` associated with the load balancer.

Changed the aliases I had for `mydomain.com` to point to the s3 bucket hosting my static content and changed the load balancer to use the new certificate.

And finally changed my web app so that it is running at `api.mydomain.com`.